# Realistic Nature (Meadow)

Tags: particles, collision

Hey guys i'm working on a nature scene and test a lot of ideas. I came to a point where a bigger plant would overgrow a way smaller one. Like a dandelion plant would do with normal gras. Everything is ready so far, but i don't get everything to collide with each other. Do i have to animate things with the timeline, to get a collision to work? The grass still pokes trough my dandelion leaves. So i guess i have to let the bigger leaves of the dandelion plant "fall" on the gras particles to get some sort of suppression to work?
I also ask myself the same about plants, sticks, rocks and so on in general. Just to simulate a little more the nature. But the other way around, by dropping everything on the gras particles.
Would something like that work with multiple particle systems - collections or objects?

I hope you can see what i mean in the picture. Most of the time only the gras makes it look odd. I would not even notice one or two dasie flowers poking trough a leaf if it would not happen this often with the gras.
[image: meadow scene]

Comment: i had the feeling collisions only kick off when animating. But what about baking the shadow of the dandelion and use that as a map so that grass particles are shorter there?

Comment: I aim for a more realistic solution, but the idea is pretty good. One could use the baked shadows to place a second particle system with kinked blades and also influence the direction in which the blades would grow further by using a weight map. 
Then again an animation would not be needed. But i really thought the settings in the particle system would use the different collision settings also to rearrange the particles right from the beginning without animating anything.

Comment: I think ppl in your situation usually let the simulation run until it settles and render the 100th frame. But as a side note on realism, in real life there wouldn't be any grass at the base of the dandelion (no root space, no light) and collision would only occur on the edge of the dandelion leaves. So maybe a mix of both methods might do it

Comment: That's what i thought too. But the most obvious eye catcher for me was the gras poking trough everything else and in general the big leaves. I think a combination would be also better, since most of the time there are just smaller areas of dandelions or dasies on a real meadow. A vertex group mixed with the shadow solution will help a lot and the inverted vertex group will make everything also a little nicer i guess. 
Is an animation to frame 100 in such a situation not slower in general, even when we only render the last frame out?

Comment: it takes some time to bake the simulation (and you'll have to rebake when you change the  leaves positions )but once that's done rendering any single frame should take the same amount of time as usual